# Is there a bash helper that show common examples while typing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a script or configuration or other tool that can show you inline most common examples of usage of given command for ex. user type:

- `tar` and it shows `tar xzvf my-archive.tar.gz`
- `ls` and it shows `ls -la`
- `xrandr` and it shows `xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1280x800`

Minimal description can be included like `extract the contents of archive` `change resolution of screen`.
Is there other method to get examples while typing in bash?

Comment: The `man` command sometimes includes examples, but if you use `info Command` instead of `man Command` you may get more information, including examples, though I wouldn't assume that what you regard as common examples will be covered. You should also look at [this link](https://ss64.com/bash/) to see if the examples there are useful to you.

Comment: Nice source of examples. What I have in mind are examples appear interactively while typing.

Comment: I've never heard of this as a requirement and I can't quite imagine how it might work within `bash`. You may have to write your own: perhaps you can extend the `complete` and `compspec` functions (see `man bash`).

Answer (score 1):

You can install the following utility on your terminal.

[howdoi](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi)

This is like having google printing direct results on your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a builtin answer, you might like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, which is "reverse search". Basically, once pressed, it searches through your command history for the most recent usage of whatever you're typing. This won't help, of course, for commands that you've never used before, but it can be quite useful.

(On the same note, I highly recommend learning [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416125/7315159) shortcuts.)

(Also, you can just create aliases for command-flag combos that you use a lot, such as `alias ll='ls -lA'`.)